# ORDS Using lower() to parameters after calling a plsql procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, case-sensitive

I'm trying to call a procedure from the URL from APEX, and I need the parameter's name to preserve the given case. For some reason I'm getting all the names in lower case and not as I wrote them.

For example:

```
<MyHost>/ords/!schema.procedure?PARAM1=value1&paRam2=VALUE2&Param3=Value3
```

But I'm getting the following:

```
param1=value1&param2=VALUE2&param3=Value3
```

As you can see, all the names have been changed to lowercase and I have not requested such change.

Is it something related to the way the ORDS is configured? Could this be re-configured?

Thanks a lot for your time an answer.